# Customizing the UIImage View

Tags: swift4, android-custom-view, custom-cell, xcode10

How to programmatically change the borderWidth of a Image view which is on a UIView and present inside a prototypeCell

I have tried changing the borderWidth in interface Builder, but it is not working.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eK1c.png)

looking forward for a better solution.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udgBE.png)

Comment: What is your imageView's frame size? Can you show use the layout of UIImageView as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
   @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
        // makes it circle if Width == Height
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.width / 2
        //Bordering
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
```